# How to add Account Related details to my custom object's lightning page

Tags: lightning

I'm very new to Salesforce and I got this test from potential employer. Here is the relevant part from test, I can't do #15:

> 11. Create a custom object ‘Visit’
>
> - with a lookup relationship to the Account Object +
>
> 15. Create a Lightning Page for the Visits object (Visits) that contains the following information: Visit details,
>
> - Account Details,
> - Assortment Products of the Account,
>
> "Assortment products" is another custom object  with a master-detail
> relationship to the Account object and  to the Product2 object.

I tried to do relevant list, no such relevant list available. I suspect "relevant record" is what I need, but I can't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are new to SFDC, I suggest creating a Trailhead account and use it to learn about SFDC, including the administrative topics.   For example, i think youre looking for Related Lists in https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_customization/lex_customization_page_layouts

Comment: No, Account doesn't show in related lists.

Comment: Just to be clear, the field is there in page layout. There are no associated details I can extract.

Comment: oh.  If you need to read Account data on the Visit__c  detail page,  then  you can consider building a formula field on the Visit__c object and its data type return definition could be Text and formula body could be , Account__r.Name, for example.   There are other solutions as well such as building a custom ui.